# Discrepancy between year rep and total rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm seeing this when I go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation :

```
** rep today: 230
** rep this week (5/15/2011 - 5/21/2011): 795
** rep this month (5/1/2011 - 5/31/2011): 1725
** rep this quarter (4/1/2011 - 6/30/2011): 5809
** rep this year (1/1/2011 - 12/31/2011): 9768
** total rep 9869 :)
```

I wasn't a member on SO (or any other SE site for that matter) until earlier this year.

I can't come up with a reason for the 101 point difference between the `rep. this year` and the `total rep`.

Can someone shed a light?

(Obviously, this is of the most capital unimportance.)

Comment: Probably, one counts the starting 1 and the association bonus of 100, but the other doesn't.`</speculation>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get 1 minimum reputation at account existence, and it can never be lost. As it can never be lost, it is never gained.

You earned +100 reputation for account association. This bonus is not tied to any point in time, and is effectively treated as if it was around since the beginning, as it is tracked as "bonus" reputation. You can lose this by getting enough downvotes, of course, but it stands that it is not post reputation like everything else.

These two elements account for the difference of 101 points.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had thought about that account association thing, and it's actually listed at the very top of the report. But the 1 minimum rep I had never thought about :-)