# Discrepancy between year rep and total rep? (another)

Tags: support, score, total-reputation

I've found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91685/discrepancy-between-year-rep-and-total-rep), and the difference in points is explained quite well. But for me, the difference is larger and I think I can't explain it.

My total reputation on Stack Overflow is 19,928, while my year's reputation is 17,080. Now, I've been a member for less than a year. Does this mean the score of other Stack Exchange sites is counted in the total? If so, why not in the year score?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You joined on 2010-11-18, so the reputation you earned during the first month and a half of your time as a member on Stack Overflow was part of the reputation earned *last year*, versus the 17,080 reputation you've earned after 2010-12-31 (this year).

Put another way, the intervals are determined based on the calendar, instead of a sliding window.

Comment: Sound and clear. Didn't think of that, but it makes complete sense. Thanks :)